# Darker and less contrasted 3D viewport and 2D canvas - Latest build of 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil, versions, theme

I just downloaded the latest build of 2.8 to try out the new grease pencil curve feature, but I've noticed something off.

The 2D canvas is significantly darker (an off grey), whereas the last build was a solid white.  I tried changing the canvas colour but nothing seems to change.

I opened a sculpt I made in this new version, and in a previous version of 2.8, and I've noticed that the brightness has gone down there too, and the contrast has also been lowered.

I went to my preferences and tried adjusting some things, but nothing seemed to help.

I understand this is an early build still.  Should I report this as a bug or is there something I can do to fix it myself?

EDIT: I should probably have mentioned that I've got the viewport colour in the shading toolbar cranked all the way to white in the 2D canvas, and it's still significantly darker than the last build.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why this happens but I fixed the issue by going to the render settings and under color management I changed the view transform from filmic to default.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me on this, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: If you watch the credits from Hero, where a bright light is shined on a beige wall and it turns yellow, you can see why this is a bad idea. The bumble mess that is Blender pixel management is not helping things.